# Swift: inherit from Class within the project

Tags: swift

How to inherit from any other class within the project? I tried to use import. But as I have read, it is used to import other packages.
The sample code is below.

```
[MyClass.swift]
class MyClass: AnotherClass { //error: use of undeclared type 'AnotherClass'

}

[AnotherClass.swift]
class AnotherClass {
     var name: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import a class from a different file you will need to mark your class as public in its declaration.

```
public class AnotherClass {
    var name: String
}
```